# How to use append method in function?

Tags: python

```
def perfect(number):
    lst = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,number):
        if number % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
            sum += i
    return sum == number

for k in range(1,1000):
    if perfect(k):
        print(k)
```

The code works well except one thing. It finds perfect numbers(ie: 6 = 1+2+3). However, I want to print those dividing numbers in a list(ie: Perfect Number:6, dividing numbers: [1,2,3]). I've tried to use append method but couldn't print it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert your list and the input number as an output of function:

```
def perfect(number):
    lst = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,number):
        if number % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
            sum += i
    return (sum == number, lst, number)
```

Then you can print it assign the list to any variable you want using unpacking:

```
(result, printList, nr) = perfect(6)
print(f"Perfect Number: {nr}, Dividing numbers: {printList}")
```

**Output**

```
Perfect Number: 6, Dividing numbers: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Please, be kind and mark my answer as 'accepted', following the Stack Overflow best practice [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to return the list:

```
def perfect(number):
    lst = []
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1,number):
        if number % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
            sum += i
    if sum == number:
        return lst
    else:
        return False

# Now the function can return either a list or False

for k in range(1,1000):
    if isinstance(perfect(k), list):
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

See this solution

```
def perfect(number):
    sum = 0
    lst = []
    for i in range(1,number):
        if number % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
            sum += i
    return ((sum == number),lst)

for k in range(1,1000):
    res,lst =  perfect(k)
    if res:
        print("{:<4} {}".format(k ,lst) )
```

**Output**

```
6    [1, 2, 3]
28   [1, 2, 4, 7, 14]
496  [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 31, 62, 124, 248]
```